# load all javascript and angularjs code before rendering the html and directive in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, settimeout, emojione

I am using emojionearea in angularJs project . when i parsed unicode to emojis smiley faces using my custom directive it gives me error Refrence Error . emojione is not defined . here is directive

```
app.directive('emojifyIt', emojifyIt);

function emojifyIt($timeout) {
  console.log('directove bya sad')
  return {
    link : function(scope, element, attributes){
      console.log(attributes['emojifyIt']);
      element.html(emojione.unicodeToImage(attributes['emojifyIt']));
    }
  };
}
```

if i use $timeout function in this it works fine. 
e.g

```
app.directive('emojifyIt', emojifyIt);

function emojifyIt($timeout) {
  console.log('directove bya sad')
  return {
    link : function(scope, element, attributes){
      console.log(attributes['emojifyIt'])
      $timeout(function() {         
        element.html(emojione.unicodeToImage(attributes['emojifyIt']))
      }, 1000);    
    }
  };
}
```

is there solution for this so that i dont use timeout function it should load script and javascript code before rendering the directive

my html code is

```
 <span emojify-it="asd"></span>
```

here is complete html file
Edited

```
  <html>
  <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="components/emojionearea/dist/emojionearea.min.css">
 <script src="components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
 <script src="components/emojionearea/dist/emojionearea.min.js"></script>
 <title>
 emoji example 
 </title>
 <style> .ng-cloak { display: none !important; } </style>
 </head>
<body ng-app="emojiApp" ng-controller="mainCtrl">

    <span   emojify-it="asd"></span> 



 <script src="components/angular/angular.js"></script>
 <script src="components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
<script>

 $(function(){
    $("#emojionearea2").emojioneArea({
pickerPosition: "bottom",
tonesStyle: "radio"
 });
  })
 </script>
```

want this result without timeout
[image: check this]

fiddle link is 
[fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/3Lqc20js/)

Comment: use watch or scope/components

Comment: how i can use that ?

Comment: How are you loading emojione?

Comment: in html file @JoelCDoyle

Comment: Haha, yes. But how, specifically? Update your question with ALL relevant code. Is emojione listed before or after your app's code?

Comment: The problem is clearly, as @JoelCDoyle suggested, the order in which you load your files. Revise that. In addition, you can use ng-cloak to hide the content until everything finished loading

Comment: I ve updates @JoelCDoyle

Comment: it says emojione is not defined . when i use timeout it works fine

Comment: i have tried the clock @yBrodsky but it still says not defined

Comment: put the emoji javascript tag below angular. That's the problem. Angular needs to load first

Comment: gettting same error @yBrodsky

Comment: create a jsfiddle or a plnkr so we can reproduce the error

Comment: here is fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/3Lqc20js/ @yBrodsky

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151971/discussion-between-asad-and-ybrodsky).

Comment: if u uncomment the timeout it will work fine @yBrodsky

Comment: it works fine out of the box. Check it yourself, open the fiddle and check that it's working

Comment: its not working man . did you try to uncomment the timeout function ? @yBrodsky

Comment: it will show you smiley faces when u will uncomment the timeout

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/QS2KW

Comment: check my updated question @yBrodsky

Comment: im talking about my directive